# How to install flask packages in Visual studio 13

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, miniconda

I have migrated from **Pycharm** to **Visual studio 2013**   to develop flask applications , am looking for a terminal like that of miniconda in pycharm to run several packages installation like :

```
pip install flask-mysql
```

etc.

How can i do this because currently i have Miniconda installed , do i have to link it to Visual studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps below:

**1.Step One :**

Right click on the icon of a flask project containing a word like **env(Python 64-bit 2.7 )** , but it depends on the version of python environment you have.

[image]

**2.Step Two :**

After right clicking select **install python package**

[image] 
**3. Step Three :**

Then you enter the command for installing a package , for example if you want to install a `mysql` package you right like this i the picture below and click **OK**:
[image]

Hope this helps you, cheers

**NB**

You can decide to just typing the package name only e.g **flask-mysql**